# How to add and modify data in QML QtCharts from Python?

Tags: python, pyside2

I would like to create a LineSeries chart in QML using ChartView with data from Python. I can easily create a LineSeries in Python and append data to it, but I don't understand how to add that data to the QML ChartView.

I've already tried creating a LineSeries in Python and connecting that to QML via engine.rootContext().setContextProperty(), but I don't see how to add the LineString to a QML ChartView. I'm also able to add LineSeries data created in QML to the Chartview, but I need to be able to define and modify the chart data in Python. It seems like the ChartView.createSeries() method is the proper channel for adding data, but I don't see how to tie data defined in Python to that method.

*Creating an Example LineSeries Chartview in QML*

```
ChartView {
    id: routechart
    title: "Routes View"
    width: 300
    Layout.rowSpan: 3
    Layout.column: 1
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    antialiasing: true

    theme: ChartView.ChartThemeDark
    // backgroundColor: "#242526"

    LineSeries {
        name: "TestSeries"
        color: "#ffcc00"
        // pointsVisible: true
        XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0 }
        XYPoint { x: 1.1; y: 2.1 }
        XYPoint { x: 1.9; y: 3.3 }
        XYPoint { x: 2.1; y: 2.1 }
        XYPoint { x: 2.9; y: 4.9 }
        XYPoint { x: 3.4; y: 3.0 }
        XYPoint { x: 4.1; y: 3.3 }
    }
}
```

*Creating a QLineSeries in Python*

```
class LineModel(QtCharts.QLineSeries):
    '''
    Model to hold XY line series data for 
    plotting.
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def addTestData(self):
        x = [0, 2, 3, 7, 10]
        y = [6, 4, 8, 4, 5]

        for xp, yp in zip(x,y):
            self.append(xp, yp)
```

*Registering the QLineSeries with the QML Engine*

```
# instantiate test LineModel
linemodel = LineModel()

# register the python type bindings to QML engine
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('LineModel', linemodel)
```

Similar to how populating a QML ListView works, I'd expect to be able to add the LineSeries from Python to the QML ChartView once the LineSeries is registered to the QML engine. However, I can't find a method within Chartview to perform this function, so there must be some alternative way to connect the data.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer specific to my code. So essentially the QML LineSeries is still being used to populate data in the chart, but the data in LineSeries is being overwritten with the QObject defined in Python? Is the line <Component.onCompleted: helper.serie = serie> setting the data in the defined helper QObject to what is defined in LineSeries, or is it setting the LineSeries data to what is defined in the helper QObject?

Comment: f you review series is a qproperty so it is recognized by QML. Going to the point, that qproperty has a getter and a setter associated with it. When you use `series = foo` in QML you are using the getter (setSerie in python). LineSeries is not overwriting the QObject but will be the value of the series qproperty.

Comment: That makes sense. So when I add data to that series in the Python 'helper' QObject after implementing  <Component.onCompleted: helper.serie = serie>, how do I get those new points to show? I've tried something like: ```@Slot()
    def addTestData(self):
        x = [0, 2, 3, 7, 10]
        y = [6, 4, 8, 4, 5]

        points = []
        for xp, yp in zip(x, y):
            points.append(QPointF(xp, yp))

        self.setLSeries(points)``` but those new points never show after calling the slot in QML.

Comment: what is `setLSeries`? In the code that I have provided you already add points in the addTestData method.

Comment: 'setLSeries' is the same function as QObject setter 'setSerie' in the code you provided. Since it already provided the functionality of overwriting the series and emitting the change, I decided to use it for those purposes in addTestData. Also added QPointF() when appending the points since the QML series expect that type.

Comment: It seems you have not understood my explanation. `setSerie(...)` makes the object created in QML accessible from python (you only have to establish a series), but if you do `setSerie(points)` you are establishing points. So your mistake is not to understand what points! = Series.

Comment: I'm going to update the code so that you understand

Comment: Thank you for the continued explanation. I see that I was overwriting the series instance with points rather than adding the points to the series. I've updated my code and can now see my points defined in Python show up on the chart.